# Remote EJB Call

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I am writing a standalone program to call the EJB. And the EJB are deployed to my local JBoss server. I follow the guideline here:
http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/jboss-as-7-remote-ejb-client-tutorial?showall=

When I execute my main problem, it throws

```
javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: JBAS013323: Invalid User
javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: JBAS013323: Invalid User
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor$1.run(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:54)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor$1.run(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:45)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:78)
```

Does anyone know what am I missing? Thanks for the help.

My main program:

```
private void start() throws Exception {

    logger.info("----------------------program start--------------------------");       
    Context context = null;         
    try {
        init();         
        final Hashtable<String, Object> jndiProperties = new Hashtable<>();
        jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context",true);
        jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"remote://localhost:4447");

        context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);

        GrainReportManagerRemote grainReportManagerRemote = (GrainReportManagerRemote) context.lookup("java:GrainEar/GrainEJB/GrainReportManager!"+ GrainReportManagerRemote.class.getName());
        grainReportManagerRemote.export();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e, e);
    } finally {
        if (context != null)
            context.close();
    }

    logger.info("----------------------program end--------------------------");
}
```

jboss-ejb-client.properties:

```
endpoint.name = client-endpoint
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS = false
remote.connection.default.host                                                     = localhost
remote.connection.default.port                                                     = 4447
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED              = false
remote.connections                                                                 = default
remote.connection.default.username=appuser
remote.connection.default.password=appuser`123
```

Comment: You don't need to reiterate the information about JNDI in your code, if you are using jboss-ejb-client.properties. Have you checked that the ejb-client.properties is in the client's classpath ?

Comment: I found that the password and username can be passed to my custom realm. However, it returns random password when I run the program every time. Besides, I have removed the ejb-clioent-properties and config the jndi setting in the program.

my problem is similar to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181141/jboss7-custom-login-module-not-working), but I follow his jndi config and it still returns random password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code on Jboss 7.1.1 and it gives me another exception: `SaslException: Authentication failed`

Please try two things that worked for me.

Either add:

```
jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");
```

or **remove** those 3 lines:

```
jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context",true);
jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"remote://localhost:4447");
```

Comment: My program can now look up the EJB and jump to my custom login module. However, the password always returns random value even I set in the jndi properties.

jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");

do you have any ideas to fix this issue?

Comment: I was not aware that you have a custom login module. I think this opens up another issue - can you ask a new question?